# Files on my WebDAV mapped drive output rendered files in IDEs instead of actual content

Tags: eclipse, macos, netbeans, textmate, webdav

On my mac I mounted a shared drive using WebDAV by going to "Finder > Go > Connect to server".

Now, when I try to view the files using TextWranger or TextEdit I can see the PHP code that I want to edit.

However, if I try to use an IDE like NetBeans/Eclipse/TextMate and create a new project with my shared drive as the "Existing sources" folder I cannot see the PHP code.

Instead I see the HTML output of the files as if I were seeing them through a web browser. Also, if I try to view a file that isn't normally accessibility (a command line script) I see the output as if it were called from the command line.

But a weird thing is if I use TextMate to edit a single file from the shared drive I can see the php code I am trying to edit. It just doesn't work as a project.

Any suggestions or solutions on how I can use an IDE to edit files over WebDAV? And why do my IDEs display the content rendered, instead of the actual file on the file system.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a specialist at all but I seem to remember that WebDAV clients do send GET requests.

If I'm correct your server may not be able to discriminate between HTTP GET and WebDAV GET thus rendering your .php files. Why this would work that way when working with a project and another way while working with individual files is not clear, though.

Do you get rendered files when you add files to your project manually as well?